# How to assign address of a int variable to unique_ptr

Tags: c++11

This is the code.

```
int main()
{
    unique_ptr <int> p {nullptr};
    int val = 100;
    p = &val;   // Not working  - compilation error
    p = move(&val);   // Not working  - compilation error
    cout << *p;
    return 0;

}
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: it's a bad idea to assign the address of automatic storage-duration variable to unique_ptr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `unique_ptr::reset`:

```
p.reset(&val);
```

Of course in this particular case this will result in undefined behavior when `p` goes out of scope and it tries to `delete` the int, but that's another matter.

Answer (score 3):

Only dynamically allocated objects should be assigned to `unique_ptr`s, because the `unique_ptr` may try to `delete` the object.

As for the actual question, the `reset()` function of `unique_ptr` is used to reassign the pointer.